# Require that a specific Haskell type defined in code is invalid

Tags: haskell, types

Is it possible to instruct GHC compiler to require that a specific value in code has invalid type, without ever using this value?

A contrived example is:

```hs
data Box a = Num a => Box a

goodBoxSample :: Box Int
goodBoxSample = Box 1

-- below definition and binding are expected to fail compilation
badBoxSample :: Box String
badBoxSample = Box "foo"
```

Is there a way to inform the compiler that badBoxSample is expected to fail (e.g. with some pragma, rather than commenting it out as a known bad sample), so that the code compiles **only** if badBoxSample fails to type-check?

The motivation here is the same as for writing a test (in some other language) with the code that is required to throw exception for the test case to pass.

Comment: Note that that syntax is very deprecated, so another example would be preferable. I'm gonna guess that it's possible to assert resolution to a `TypeError`, but wait for someone else to actually try to do it :)

Comment: @moonGoose, that syntax (`ExistentialQuantification`) is not deprecated at all, though `GADTs` syntax is often clearer. You're probably thinking of `DatatypeContexts`, which allows types that look similar but are a bit different: `data Num a => Box a = Box a`.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. You're basically asking for a way to prove that there's no `instance Num String`, but Haskell operates under the open-world assumption, which means that someone could always declare such an instance.

Comment: Compilation would still fail in case such instance is not found...

Answer (score 0):

Somebody posted a very helpful answer here, but before I managed to accept it was removed... Thank you anyway, and here it is for the reference:

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-lens-2.0.0.0/docs/Data-Generics-Product-Fields.html

In short, the goal of testing failing types can be achieved with [doctest](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/doctest), in the way the linked library does it.

Comment: That post was deleted by a moderator as link-only. You should bring actual content into your answer if you don't want it deleted too.

Comment: I don’t think it was - it was saying it can be done with doctest pointing to the example - there isn’t much to add... Was it from you :)?

Comment: I had nothing to do with it.